# How do we download Amazon Advertising Api reports?

Tags: python, report, amazon-advertising-api

I am working on a sandbox environment and I am trying to download the report  based on the https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/v2/reference/reports
The issue is that the report which is downloaded is empty. Doesn't contain any data inside. How do we download the report from amazon advertising api?

I follow this steps as described: https://gist.github.com/dbrent-amazon/ca396a63c1670ee0ec83aad26b0ce55b

Comment: please include your code

Comment: @QHarr i included a link with the exact steps i follow.

Answer (score 5):

here's a script that works for me using python and requests, make sure to:

1. create a campaign, adGroupd and keywords
2. create reports with the right metrics
3. make sure you have actual data to view in the report
4. make sure reportDate is correct

```py
import requests

version = 'v2'
advertise = 'sp'

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token.access}",
    "Amazon-Advertising-API-ClientId": AmazonSecurityProfile.ClientID,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

class urls:
    class api:
        test = 'https://advertising-api-test.amazon.com'

# create report
recordType = "keywords"
r = requests.post(
    f'{urls.api.test}/{version}/{advertise}/{recordType}/report',
    json={
      # "campaignType": "sponsoredProducts",
      "segment": "query",
      "reportDate": '20201025',  #YYYYMMDD
      "metrics": ",".join([
          "campaignName",
          "campaignId",
          "campaignStatus",
          "campaignBudget",
          "clicks",
          "cost",
          "attributedConversions1d",
          "attributedConversions7d",
          "attributedConversions1dSameSKU",
          "attributedConversions7dSameSKU",
          "attributedUnitsOrdered1d",
          "attributedUnitsOrdered7d",
          "attributedSales1d",
          "attributedSales7d",
          "attributedSales1dSameSKU",
          "attributedSales7dSameSKU",
          "attributedUnitsOrdered1dSameSKU",
          "attributedUnitsOrdered7dSameSKU",
          "adGroupName",
          "adGroupId",
          "keywordText",
          "keywordId",
          "matchType",
          "impressions",
      ]),
    },
    headers=headers,
)
r.raise_for_status()
r = r.json()
print(r)
reportId = r["reportId"]

while r['status'] == 'IN_PROGRESS':
    r = requests.get(
        f'{urls.api.test}/{version}/reports/{reportId}',
        headers=headers,
    )
    r = r.json()
    print(r)

assert r['status'] == 'SUCCESS'

r = requests.get(
    r["location"],
    headers=headers,
)
print(r)
```